# 17.10 How to remove painful screen tearing with Nvidia-Intel GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I had recently installed Ubuntu on my Sager Notebook Computer , and I noticed after a while that there was a LOT of screen tearing on my PC. I started researching the topic and found a lot of solutions. The first thing I tried was installing nvidia drivers using

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

This did not fix my problem.

I then tried to change the settings in Nvidia X Server Settings, but it said that "PRIME Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings and must be configured by an external RandR capable tool. The display is shown in the layout window for information purposes only"

[Nvidia X Server PRIME Display Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfyaT.png)

I then tried to install CompizConfig and change the refresh rate to >144 Hertz, but that also did not effect anything.

After some more research I tried to use the xrandr command to change the refresh rate, but that also had no effect.

I tried to disable Wayland and enable GDM3, yet that also yielded no change.

I then tried installing Bumblebee in hopes of fixing the sync, but that had no effect, and even Soft-Bricked my computer later.

Here are my specs : http://www.sagernotebook.com/Notebook-NP7870.html

Comment: Did you take a look at possible solutions like https://askubuntu.com/questions/941077/screen-tearing-on-nvidia-gtx960m

Comment: yes I did indeed

Comment: The Nvidia X Server Settings have no options

Comment: That's because you installed the wrong Nvidia drivers. The `nvidia-current` actually is 340, an old driver with extended support only to used for legacy hardware and that certainly isn't the case.

Comment: **UPDATE**

I found the solution to my problem HERE : 

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449

Don't worry if the file /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf is missing, just create it if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem [HERE](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449).

Don't worry if the file `/etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf` is missing, just create it if it is.

Comment: Note that starting in 18.04 you no longer specify driver version. Ex. of doing via a .conf here, otherwise one can add to grub's linix command line. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2385770&p=13748694&viewfull=1#post13748694 (-also note that users should note upgrade drom 17.10 to 18.04 with nvidia drivers installed, problems will occur. 18.04 is best served on a fresh install..

Comment: Please do not post answers that depend on a link. Include the important information directly into your answer. [answer]