# Ubuntu 17.10 Nvidia XORG settings do not save (resolution, orientation, hz, color correction... etc)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

Ubuntu 17.10.1. Nvidia Driver 384.111 
3 Monitors (1440p 144z, 1080p 144hz, 1080p vertical) 
My settings DO NOT SAVE, they dont. I have tried everything from scripts to changing Xinitrc files. Every boot/login just resets to defualt ubuntu display. Im doing something wrong?

First of all. I'd like to vent, HOW ON EARTH isnt there a default backup, A PROPER defualt back up, for nvidia settings. 
IVE WENT THROUGH MULTIPLE forums, 7 so far.. nothing works.

Save X to config, doesnt work. I save it to /etc/x11/ & /etc/x11/Xsession.d
more and more and more. I have tried many things to fix this. Ive reinstalled OS, Manjaro Deepin, Pop OS, Ubuntu 17.10.1.
None of it saves my settings. **I have read and read and read. Ive tried this,**

q

The NVIDIA X driver does not preserve values set with nvidia-settings
between runs of the X server (or even between logging in and logging
out of X, with xdm, gdm, or kdm).  This is intentional, because
different users may have different preferences, thus these settings
are stored on a per user basis in a configuration file stored in
the user's home directory.

The configuration file is named "~/.nvidia-settings-rc".  You can
specify a different configuration file name with the "--config"
commandline option.

After you have run nvidia-settings once and have generated a
configuration file, you can then run:

```
nvidia-settings --load-config-only
```

at any time in the future to upload these settings to the X
server again.  For example, you might place the above command in
your ~/.xinitrc file so that your settings are applied automatically
when you log in to X.

Your .xinitrc file, which controls what X applications should
be started when you log into X (or startx), might look something
like this:

```
nvidia-settings --load-config-only &
xterm &
evilwm
```

or:

```
nvidia-settings --load-config-only &
gnome-session
```

If you do not already have an ~/.xinitrc file, then chances are that
xinit is using a system-wide xinitrc file.  This system wide file
is typically here:

```
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

To use it, but also have nvidia-settings upload your settings,
you could create an ~/.xinitrc with the contents:

```
nvidia-settings --load-config-only &
. /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

System administrators may choose to place the nvidia-settings load
command directly in the system xinitrc script.

Please see the xinit(1) manpage for further details of configuring
your ~/.xinitrc file.

q

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hsa0ebZKfys

Ive done that too.. It just doesnt work. WHY?

Please help me, the reality is that I'm def ignorant. Could be something under my nose but I dont know.

Comment: My experience was nothing like yours: https://askubuntu.com/questions/941077/screen-tearing-on-nvidia-gtx960m/985021#985021